# How to implement swipe to reveal cell from both sides

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

How to implement swipe to reveal cell from both right and left side using auto layout and swift.

For example when user swipe to right side I need to reveal some labels and if user swipe to left side I want to reveal some buttons.

Comment: This may help you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views

Comment: This way you can set it programatically: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swtableviewcell-expose-utility-buttons-with-an-easy-to-use-uitableviewcell-subclass/

Answer (score 1):

This is a good one for use with cocoapods:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/MGSwipeTableCell

Refer to this for use with swift:

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell/issues/19